# Android menuItem setChecked doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml

### I have this menu  filters.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
           <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/menuGroup_1"  >
                <item android:id="@+id/a_1"  android:title="a1" />
                <item  android:id="@+id/a_2" android:title="a2" />
            </group>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single" android:id="@+id/menuGroup_2"    >
                <item  android:id="@+id/b_1" android:title="b1" />
                <item android:id="@+id/b_2" android:title="b2"  />
            </group>

</menu>
```

---

### and here are the methods in the .java:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.filters, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

         return true;
    }
```

This works fine checkableBehavior="single", but the item doesn't uncheck when I press. Still checked. (item.isChecked()->true)

---

I try to edit the .xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/..."   android:checkable = "true"  />
```

Now when a select any item they check/uncheck correcltry, 
 but this checkableBehavior="single" doesn't work. In other words, I can check two items of the same group.

Answer (score -1):

you should let `onOptionsItemSelected` return `true`;